# Can I close emt ell in wall?

Tags: electrical, conduit

I know that it will be difficult to impossible to fish anything through it later, but can I close up emt in the wall with a 90-degree ell (uncurved)?

It's easier for me to use rigid conduit for this run but there is a section where I don't have the clearance for a curve. I can get wiring in now but I don't want to leave the elbow accessible after I put in drywall.

Something like this [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000VYGZWM/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_Y4vjCbJ2PPE1P](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000VYGZWM)

I'm in California.

Comment: Is this ell a conduit body like an LB ? Or are you talking about a 90 with an access port?

Comment: @Ed_Beal No access port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:  no, you can't bury a pulling elbow, the cover must remain accessible.

It may be tempting, but really it's better to find another way.

As mentioned in the comments - you could add an access panel in the drywall, and make the pull elbow accessible. You could even hang a picture over the access panel.  You could install a pull box with the cover accessible.

Comment: What if I was an inaccessible elbow? No pulling access?

Comment: @Matthew, not sure what you're asking... you have to be able to get to the cover of the pull elbow without cutting drywall or etc.  It's OK if there's an access cover that you can unscrew and get to it, that would be considered accessible. No such restriction for a bend in the conduit, a bend doesn't have to be accessible.

Comment: Like this Halex 02910 Electrical Metallic Tubing 90Degree Compression Elbows Short Zinc Die Cast (5 Piece), 1" https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000VYGZWM/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_Y4vjCbJ2PPE1P

Comment: @matthew - I see, a short radius connector instead of a pull elbow - You'll notice that those short radius elbow are not made as couplings, not made to accept the conduit on both sides - they are elbow box connectors, made to go from conduit into a box so, they don't really help.  (You could bastardize by attaching a threaded coupling and threaded connector but you'd only be fooling yourself - not an inspector.)

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of using a threaded coupling to attach it, it won't pass muster, eh?

Comment: @Matthew - afraid not. I don't think it would pass - it would probably fail based on you're not using the short radius elbow fitting according to it's listing - bastardizing is violating.

Comment: The answer is WRONG that elbow can be concealed. That's why I asked if it was an LB or a short radius 90 with a cover plate, it could be used how you intend I can show these in use in industrial installs where space was an issue.

Comment: @EdBeal - I see violations in industrial facilities all the time, way worse than this LOL

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to build a little cabinet door.  You must be able to access the elbow's cover plate, without disassembling the building in any way which is destructive, and without using tools.

Another way is to find a pretense to put a receptacle or blank junction box cover there.

Comment: Consider putting in fishing strings instead.

Comment: That elbow doesn't have a cover,  so it could be concealed. I know we use them on occasion at the mill mid run where we don't need access as long as a push pull with the wire to keep it from being dammaged it could be used but a residential inspector may flag it.

Comment: @EdBeal I cannot believe my eyes.  It does look like it's for EMT.   How on earth do you fish/pull through it?  My fishing tape won't bend that sharp.

Comment: A string to pull and some one to push the wire into the conduit, as long as the outter jacket is only damaged it meets code requirements. Even with long sweeps the outter jacket can be damaged but as long as the wire insulation is not damaged it will be fine.